How to properly use a setter with SQLAlchemy and FastAPI?
In my project I have a model with a association_table and a custom getter and setter to simplify API handling. This is my model:
association_table = Table(
    "association_table_check_page",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("left_id", ForeignKey("page.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True),
    Column("right_id", ForeignKey("check.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True),
)


class Page(Base):
    checks: Mapped[list[Check]] = relationship(
        "Check",
        secondary=association_table,
        passive_deletes=True,
    )

    @property
    def check_ids(self):
        return [check.id for check in self.checks]

    @check_ids.setter
    def check_ids(self, check_ids):
        from creyPY.fastapi.crud import get_object_or_404

        sess = Session.object_session(self)

        if not sess:
            raise Exception("Object is not associated with a session")

        self.checks = [get_object_or_404(Check, check_id, sess) for check_id in check_ids]

When I try to update the object, the exception is raised. I used to get a new database session in case the object_session is None, but as it always is None, I get different other errors.
This is the update method I call from my endpoint:
def update_obj_from_data(
    data: BaseModel,
    model: Type[T],
    id: UUID | str,
    db: Session,
    partial: bool = False,
    ignore_fields=[],
    additional_data={},
    exclude={},
) -> T:
    obj = get_object_or_404(model, id, db)
    data_dict = data.model_dump(exclude_unset=not partial, exclude=exclude)
    data_dict.update(additional_data)  # merge additional_data into data_dict
    for field in data_dict:
        if field not in ignore_fields:
            setattr(obj, field, data_dict[field])
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(obj)
    return obj

How can I properly attach the session to the object? Or should it already be attached? I am new to SQLAlchemy, so I am open to suggestions on how to properly solve this. I tried adding db.add(obj) in the beginning of the update_obj_from_data, but it didn't make a difference.

What is get_object_or_404? Can you share the code?

@snakecharmerb Yes, I just didn't want to overload the question with details. This is the code: https://github.com/creyD/creyPY/blob/master/creyPY/fastapi/crud.py
